# l2tp vpn is disconnected after few minutes

Tags: vpn, ipsec, l2tp, openswan

I installed IPSec/L2TP on my vps server.

I tried to connect from my mac to this VPN server.

First time, connection is succeeded. But after a few minutes, connection was broken by itself.

After this, I tried to connection again and connection was failed.

```
pppd[7407]: pppd 2.4.2 (Apple version 727.1.15) started by albert, uid 501
pppd[7407]: L2TP connecting to server '174.128.103.32' (174.128.103.32)...
pppd[7407]: IPSec connection started
racoon[7408]: plogsetfile: about to add racoon log file: /var/log/racoon.log
racoon[7408]: accepted connection on vpn control socket.
racoon[7408]: Connecting.
racoon[7408]: IPSec Phase 1 started (Initiated by me).
racoon[7408]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Initiator, Main-Mode message 1).
racoon[7408]: >>>>> phase change status = Phase 1 started by us
racoon[7408]: >>>>> phase change status = Phase 1 started by peer
racoon[7408]: IKE Packet: receive success. (Initiator, Main-Mode message 2).
racoon[7408]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Initiator, Main-Mode message 3).
racoon[7408]: IKE Packet: receive success. (Initiator, Main-Mode message 4).
racoon[7408]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Initiator, Main-Mode message 5).
racoon[7408]: IKEv1 Phase 1 AUTH: success. (Initiator, Main-Mode Message 6).
racoon[7408]: IKE Packet: receive success. (Initiator, Main-Mode message 6).
racoon[7408]: IKEv1 Phase 1 Initiator: success. (Initiator, Main-Mode).
racoon[7408]: IPSec Phase 1 established (Initiated by me).
racoon[7408]: IPSec Phase 2 started (Initiated by me).
racoon[7408]: >>>>> phase change status = Phase 2 started
racoon[7408]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Initiator, Quick-Mode message 1).
racoon[7408]: IKE Packet: receive success. (Initiator, Quick-Mode message 2).
racoon[7408]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Initiator, Quick-Mode message 3).
racoon[7408]: IKEv1 Phase 2 Initiator: success. (Initiator, Quick-Mode).
racoon[7408]: IPSec Phase 2 established (Initiated by me).
racoon[7408]: >>>>> phase change status = Phase 2 established
pppd[7407]: IPSec connection established
pppd[7407]: L2TP cannot connect to the server
racoon[7408]: IPSec disconnecting from server 174.128.103.32
racoon[7408]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Information message).
racoon[7408]: IKEv1 Information-Notice: transmit success. (Delete IPSEC-SA).
racoon[7408]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Information message).
racoon[7408]: IKEv1 Information-Notice: transmit success. (Delete ISAKMP-SA).
racoon[7408]: glob found no matches for path "/var/run/racoon/*.conf"
racoon[7408]: pfkey DELETE failed: No such file or directory
racoon[7408]: Connecting.
racoon[7408]: Unknown Informational exchange received.
```

So, on my server, I tried

```
service ipsec restart
service xl2tpd restart
```

But connection was failed as before.

After 30~40 minutes, I tried again and connection was succeeded. After a few minutes, the same phenomenon occurred.

The server has two network card.

eth0's ip address 174.128.103.32, eth1's ip address is 10.177.209.15

What's wrong? Please help me.

Followings are my configuration files.

**/etc/ipsec.conf**

```
version 2.0
config setup
    nat_traversal=yes
    virtual_private=%v4:10.0.0.0/8,%v4:192.168.0.0/16,%v4:172.16.0.0/12
    oe=off
    protostack=netkey
conn L2TP-PSK
    authby=secret
    pfs=no
    auto=add
    keyingtries=%forever
    rekey=yes
    ikelifetime=8h
    keylife=1h
    type=transport
    left=174.128.103.32
    leftnexthop=%defaultroute
    leftprotoport=17/1701
    right=%any
    rightprotoport=17/%any
```

**/etc/sysctl.conf**

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects = 0
```

**/etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf**

```
[global]
ipsec saref = no
listen-addr=174.128.103.32
port = 1701

[lns default]
ip range = 192.168.20.100-192.168.20.200
local ip = 192.168.20.1
refuse chap = yes
refuse pap = yes
require authentication = yes
name = l2tpd
ppp debug = yes
pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd
length bit = yes
```

**/etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd**

```
require-mschap-v2
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 4.2.2.1
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
proxyarp
asyncmap 0
auth
crtscts
lock
hide-password
modem
debug
```

**/etc/ppp/chap-secrets**

```
user1  l2tpd  user1password  *
```

**/etc/iptables/rule.v4**

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

**/etc/ipsec.secrets**

```
include /var/lib/openswan/ipsec.secrets.inc
```

**/var/lib/openswan/ipsec.secrets.inc**

```
#: RSA /etc/ipsec.d/private/key.pem
%any : PSK "password"
```

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does the log of the other endpoint contain any usable information?

Comment: what is the content of racoon conf file ? ( see racoon[7408]: glob found no matches for path "/var/run/racoon/*.conf" )